# Issue with moving drawable and Imageview layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

So we want to make a game in which we move a balloon with an Android phone's accelerometer. There will be obstacles probably created using ImageView's that cause the balloon to pop when they collide. So far, we got the ImageView balloon to move, but it seems as though the drawable (called yellow_balloon) is only able to be seen INSIDE the ImageView balloon's layout.

The java code:

```
package com.ec327.ballon;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;

public class GameScreen extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private ImageView balloon=null;
    final String tag = "AccLogger";
    SensorManager sensore=null;

    int xa=0;
    int ya=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_screen);

        sensore = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);     

        balloon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.balloon);
        balloon.scrollTo(xa, ya);
        //balloon.offsetLeftAndRight(50);
        //balloon.offsetTopAndBottom(50);

        //balloon.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_balloon);

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
         Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
         float [] values = event.values;
         synchronized (this) {
                 Log.d(tag, "onSensorChanged: " + sensor + ", x: " +
                                 values[0] + ", y: " + values[1] + ", z: " + values[2]);
         if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER ) {

             xa=(int)values[0];// this part of code is only test to see int x and y on Activity
             ya=(int)values[1];

         }
         }
         balloon.scrollBy(xa, ya);
         balloon.invalidate();
      }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        Log.d(tag,"onAccuracyChanged: " + sensor + ", accuracy: " + accuracy);
     }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Sensor Accel = sensore.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
       // register this class as a listener for the orientation and accelerometer sensors
        sensore.registerListener((SensorEventListener) this, Accel,        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
      }
}
```

The XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/blank_screen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/balloon"
        android:layout_width="41dp"
        android:layout_height="142dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/yellow_balloon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the xml file, ImageView balloon has a layout_width=41dp and layout_height=142dp. When the program runs, the yellow_balloon moves around, but once it moves outside the layout dimensions of ImageView balloon, it can't be seen anymore.

Does scrollBy() only move the drawable yellow_balloon and not the actual balloon layout's position? We've tried using that as well as layout.setMargins, but neither are working. We've also tried using setOffsetTopAndBottom and setOffsetLeftAndRight, but that does not move the ImageView of the balloon. What's causing this problem and how do we fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure using imageViews is the easiest or most efficient way of doing what you are doing, especially if you want to create obstacles for the balloon to collide into and pop.

My suggestion would be that your game is done entirely inside of a SurfaceView. From here you would be able to add in "Sprites" which would be all of your objects (your Balloon, your obstacles) and you can have it check for sprite collisions (your cases where the balloon would pop).

The problem with imageviews is that you are going to need to move the entire image and once you are introducing multiple images, unless the box around the image is entirely full with the picture you will begin to get picture overlaps or collisions before the actual collision occurs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. Everything is working very smoothly now.